# JMeter Problem with the variable in JSR223 PreProcessor

Tags: java, jmeter, preprocessor

I send POST request with the following JSON in body data

[image]

The problem is that the unixTimeValue variable is not setting

This is how my JSR223 PreProcessor looks like
[image]
\

Answer (score 1):

`vars` hold String values, you can convert your double when putting value:

```
vars.put("unixTimeValue", String.valueOf(a));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can change your lines 1-14 to:

   ```
   vars.put("RANDOM_STRING", org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils.randomAscii(12))
   ```

   See [RandomStringUtils class JavaDoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html) for more potentially useful functions
2. Change your line 20 to:

   ```
   vars.putObject("unixTimeValue", sin);
   ```

   as `vars.put()` function accepts only Strings while `vars.putObject()` accepts pretty much everything, see [JMeterVariables class JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) for more details
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting mainly because Groovy has much better performance comparing to Beanshell, see [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for comprehensive explanation with examples